# Reuse Asus Netbook webcam on PC USB Port

Tags: usb, cable, camera

i try to use the webcam of my old 1101HA EEEPC from Asus with the intention of connecting it up to a computer via USB. I just can`t find the right cablecolors for this specific board. Supposedly this webcam has a USB interface (was recognized as USB device in Taskmanager)

I would like to know what I would need to do to connect this board (picture of connector pins) to a normal USB- Cable. Maybe someone did and can help we with the colors ? I hoped somebody maybe did this before with this model and got a datasheert or mainboard circuit sheet. I do this just out of curiosity and because i like experimenting.

[image: the board]

Comment: it has violet, green, blue, yellow, orange, red, brown and black as cablecolors. Some are for microphone for sure. thanks already!

Comment: The colours tell you **nothing**. If a cable with different colors was cheaper, they would have used that. What matters are the signals, GND, VDD, D+ and D-. If this confuses you then maybe this mod is not for you. Also: **EDIT** your question instead of adding comments to it.

Comment: Other than finding a datasheet, there is no way to know.

Comment: If the computer was working, you could measure the voltages on the different pins and get a hint about what colors were what. If it doesn't, then it's really hard. The ground wire is the easiest to find (it's connected to the large planes on the board). the Vcc can be thicker than the others, or try to find some large capacitors on the board which can be the bypass or tank capacitors. As for the signals, youìll have to be really lucky. Try finding two wires which go to the same IC with parallel tracesor lentgth-matching patterns (like [these](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0TxCW.jpg))

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pin-out for the camera of Eee PC 1015cx laptop.

[image]

[image]
Sorry the Wiring is inverted in the second Image